# local git repository with password protection

Tags: git

I would like to create a local git repository with password protection. Its like even if the repository is on my laptop, it should require a password to view its content. Is it possible? if yes, then suggest a way to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Git does not provide such a feature. If you want password protection, you could resort to an encrpyted file system. However, once such a file system has been mounted, the normal access control of your operating system applies.